# Google Maps API v3; web service request and using for-loop to display multiple locations

Tags: javascript, web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, for-loop

I am new to javascript, so I apologize if my questions are unclear. I will try to clarify as best as possible.

What I am trying to accomplish:
Getting the google map to populate with gyms according to your current location. (Currently it populates with only one gym and only for the coordinates entered when I remove for loop and input 0 in the places of i)

I am trying to create a for loop so that it runs through the block of code multiple times and adds up to 12 markers to the map based on the search and in the users current location.

I also have not been able to figure out how to add the user's geolocation into the httpRequest. I tried making a variable "both" (I commented it out) that when put under location in the httprequest it would input the users current latitude and longitude.

Here is a chunk of my code:

```
function handler_actionBtn8_onClick(mouseev){

//console.log("in button click at top " + latitude + longitude);
// both = [latitude,longitude];

for (var i=0; i<12; i++){

var data = app.httpRequest(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.265319,-95.948305&radius=1000&types=gym&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCKnE1Fk2JKQXjhYuVuBK1uPZOz_bpNZRQ", 
    "GET", 

        function(data, error, httpResponse){
        if (error === false){
        console.log("in function if, error was false");
        console.log("data.results[i].name is " + data.results[i].name);
        console.log("the lng is " + data.results[i].geometry.location.lng);
        console.log("the lat is " + data.results[i].geometry.location.lat);

        // now need to display in map widget
        var temp = [data.results[i].geometry.location.lat, data.results[i].geometry.location.lng];
        app.setValue("googlemap", temp);
       // app.setProperty("gmap", "longitude", data.results[i].geometry.location.lng);
        //app.setProperty("gmap", "latitude", data.results[i].geometry.location.lat);         
    } else {
        app.showMessage("AJAX Error", "Cannot locate it");
        console.log("here is the error place data", data);
    }
    }, {}, "JSON"); 
}
}
```

I also have a chunk of code I didn't include that finds the geolocation and then has the variables latitude and longitude which i was trying to use in this portion to add it to location.

Once again sorry if this is unorganized, I wil try to clarify or include anything else I need.

Answer (score 0):

Is this javascript running on a web site or phone app or what?

I can't properly test your code as your api key is specific to your domain (CORS) and your info is a little vague but from looking at what you have above, you will need to restructure your code a bit:
you should move the httpRequest outside of your forloop for starters, as you're making the same request 12 times and instead, loop through `data.results` array for the request and add each marker/location to your map then.